# SQL Server Installation Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: sql-server, installation

I am trying to install Microsoft SQL Server, but whenever I try to do so, the Database Engine Services feature fails and I get the following error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

This has happened on Enterprise & Developer editions, both 2016 and 2017. The summary log isn't particularly helpful (at least that I can see), and the only other advice I've found is to make sure .NET Frameworks 3.5 and 4 are enabled on the PC.

Please see [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/z6m56udfok1j4v8/AADSkyIlCSx8GTbRKDybjm6ua?dl=0) for summary, detail, and what I believe are the error logs. If anything else is needed I'll drop it in that folder as well.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Google "Configuration action failed for feature SQL_Engine_Core_Inst during timing ConfigRC and scenario ConfigRC."-- are you in the administrators group of your PC?

Comment: @TonyHinkle Yeah, I am an admin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Details.txt log shows an error of:

```
(01) 2018-02-07 01:38:44 Slp:     Inner exception type: System.OverflowException
(01) 2018-02-07 01:38:44 Slp:         Message: 
(01) 2018-02-07 01:38:44 Slp:                 Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.
(01) 2018-02-07 01:38:44 Slp:         HResult : 0x80131516
(01) 2018-02-07 01:38:44 Slp:         Stack: 
(01) 2018-02-07 01:38:44 Slp:                 at SNIOpenSyncExWrapper(SNI_CLIENT_CONSUMER_INFO* , SNI_ConnWrapper** )
```

As the first error that occurs, when it initially attempts to connect to the database engine. This might be the better error to chase down, since it seems to indicate something interfering with the connection. A quick search [shows some similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32609088/arithmetic-overflow-exception-when-opening-sql-connection) with people running Lavasoft (Adaware, etc) Software - any chance you're running this?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I wasn't running Lavasoft but the dlls were still present: removing these seems to have fixed the issue. Thanks a lot!